# Obtaining weather station data from a MySQL database

Tags: php, performance, mysql

I have a PHP page for a weather station that I'm trying to build.

I run multiple queries to pull out data from a MySQL database for min/max/average values for temp, pressure, humidity etc.

All of these are done by multiple MySQL select statements - here are 2 of them:

```
 $sql_dht22_temp_max = "select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i'), dht22_temp from weather inner join (select max(dht22_temp) as ts from weather where date(date) = curdate()) as ds on weather.dht22_temp = ds.ts order by date desc limit 1;";

if (!$result = $db->query($sql_dht22_temp_max)){
        die('error 1');
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $dht22_temp_max = $row['dht22_temp'];
        $dht22_max_date = $row["DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i')"];
}

$sql_inside_temp_min = "select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i'), temperature from inside_temp inner join (select min(temperature) as ts from inside_temp where date(date) = curdate()) as ds on inside_temp.temperature = ds.ts order by date desc limit 1;";


if(!$result = $db->query($sql_inside_temp_min)){
    die('error running query');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $inside_temp_min = $row['temperature'];
    $inside_min_date = $row["DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i')"];
}
```

While each statement takes a few milliseconds to run, adding them all up and it takes about 3-4 seconds. So on loading my page, you have to wait 3-4 seconds, which doesn't seem like much but is a pain.

If there a better way of doing this? Running all the statement in parallel? Can the MySQL/PHP code be optimized?

```
explain select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') As MyDate, dht22_temp 
    from weather inner join (select min(dht22_temp) as ts from weather 
    where date(date) = curdate()) as ds on weather.dht22_temp = ds.ts 
    order by date desc limit 1;


# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', 'system', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', NULL
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'weather', 'index', NULL, 'id_date', '9', NULL, '1', 'Using where'
'2', 'DERIVED', 'weather', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '65420', 'Using where'
```

Here is the table structure:

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'idweather', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'date', 'datetime', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'rainfall', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'windspeed', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'dewpoint', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'pressure', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'bmp085_temp', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'dht22_temp', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'abs_hum', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'gust', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'uvi', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'light', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'rel_humidity', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'wind_dir', 'varchar(5)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Comment: Maybe use this http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.multi-query.php so you output your rows in a single while.Aliases will be your friend.Also your table definitions,indexes  and EXPLAIN would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You SQL commands seem rather overelaborated. Let me first rewrite it in a more readable way:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i'), dht22_temp 
FROM weather 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT max(dht22_temp) as ts 
  FROM weather 
  WHERE date(date) = curdate()) 
AS ds ON weather.dht22_temp = ds.ts 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If I understand it correctly it seems you want to know at what time today the maximum temperate was reached and what that temperature was. You use the table `weather` with `date` and `dht22_temp` columns. In contrast to what you might think, I would start by splitting this command in two parts:

```
SELECT idweather, dht22_temp
FROM weather
WHERE date(date) = curdate()
ORDER BY dht22_temp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will execute quite fast and return the maximum temperature today, and the row where that maximum occured. Please make sure `dht22_temp` is properly indexed. Also note that this assumes that there's only 1 maximum. This might not be correct, and you can check that by reading more rows (increase `LIMIT`). Now you can check all kind of stuff that happened when the temperature was at its maximum:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather
WHERE idweather = <id of max temp>
```

This is very simple, but it gives you all the weather parameters when the temperature was at its maximum, including the time at which it occured. A lot of data in two simple steps.

Don't overcomplicate your SQL. But the main point is: **Use your auto increment index!**

I am, of course, making a point here. Once you've seen that we can rewrite the two SQL commands into a single one, reducing it to what was needed:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') as time, dht22_temp
FROM weather
WHERE date(date) = curdate()
ORDER BY dht22_temp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And doesn't that look much simpler? In your case however I would just grab the data for one whole day:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather
WHERE date(date) = curdate()
```

and read it in an array. Then do the manipulation, like sorting, in memory. You could even make a histogram this way, without having to access the database again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Some good points there - I will have a look into the indexes as well. On your first example you use SELECT idweather, dht22_temp. What is idweather?

Comment: Ignore the above: Its working great - a lot faster too. It seems a lot simpler especially sorting than what I was doing! I also like the idea of reading it into an array as I would like to do a histogram at some stage as well.